# Does this equation has a closed form solution?

Tags: taylor-expansion, closed-form, rational-functions

We have $K$ non-negative coefficients: $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_K,A_1,A_2,\dots,A_K$, where $A_i\geq0,\;a_i\in(0,1),\;\sum A_i<T$. The equation is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^K\frac{A_i}{1-a_ix}=T,\quad x\in(0,1)$$

Comment: Whether or not it has a closed form solution is going to depend on the actual coefficients. Basically if you subtract T and then put everything over a common denominator, the problem will reduce down to finding the roots of a polynomial, and only some polynomials have closed form roots

Comment: So, if $K>4$, then the equation in general has no closed form solution, since polynomial with degree over 4 in general has no closed form solution, right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I thought there would be no closed form if $K$ was $\infty$.